# Unable to print with many PrintDataGrid in flex

Tags: apache-flex, printing

I have a title window with 3 datagrids in it and I have to add print functionality.
Basically I have three PrintDataGrids with dynamic data on its printview file. Issue is I am not able to get print in right way. It works fine with small data.
But if I have any datagrid with large data issue occurs, that datagrid goes on next page as validNextPage() is true for that only.So sequence of printing spoils.

Answer (score 0):

i think the most reliable way to print is generate a PDF out of the datagrid rows and go from there. an example of that is [here](http://blog.kreatx.com/2011/11/11/flex-printing-print-preview-pdf-generation/)